# Craft can't connect to db.php on live server

Tags: config

My Craft files are structured correctly, I have the Craft file level with the `public_html` file on the server (which contains the `index.php` file), within `index.php` I have set my `$craftpath` correctly to `$craftPath = '../craft';`.

But when I go to my live url I get a Craft styled error of:

```
Service Unavailable
Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.
```

When I try to reach my admin I get an error of:

```
Error error
Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php.
```

If it helps, my general.php file looks like this:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true
    ),

    // development
    'example.dev' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'devMode' => true,
            'siteUrl'  => 'http://example.dev/',
            'assetPath' => 'http://example.dev/assets/'
        )
    ),

    // production
    'example.com' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'devMode' => false,
            'siteUrl'  => 'http://example.com/',
            'assetPath' => 'http://example.com/assets/'
        )
    )
);
```

And the db.php file is as such:

```
return array(
    '*' => array (
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    ),
    'example.dev' => array (
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'localdatabase',
    ),
    'example.com' => array (
        'cooldownDuration' => 0,
        'server' => 'server',
        'user' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database',
    )
);
```

I hope you can help becuase I'm lossing my mind as to whats wrong, but I'm sure it's something minor that I'm overlooking.

Comment: The `cooldownDuration` setting should go in your `general.php` config file, not in your `db.php` config file. On your server, is the db on a separate server or is it on the same server? If so, the value for server in `example.com` should be `localhost` not `server`.

Comment: @SteveRowling: You should post that as an official answer, so Spheriri can accept it and others can upvote it. Great catch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cooldownDuration` setting should go in your `general.php` config file, not in your `db.php` config file. On your server, is the db on a separate server or is it on the same server? If so, the value for server in example.com should be `localhost` not `server`.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Steve! It worked! Thought it would be a silly error somewhere.